# Регулярные выражения - выделение целых чисел из строки

Tags: python, python-3.x

Дана строка, необходимо вывести все целые числа через запятую

```
import re


inp = '''ghfjfjfj 5 jfjfkffk 8 jffjkkd 1989 
         fjhfjddkkd 7 jkdkddldll 8.5 '''
if inp:
    textlookfor = r'[0-9]+'
    res = re.findall(textlookfor, inp)

print(','.join(res))
```

аутпут:

```
5,8,1989,7,8,5
```

А правильный должен быть без 8 и 5. В общем, мой код засчитывает числа float. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно исправить? На выходе должны быть только целые неотрицательные числа, все остальные должны игнорироваться

Comment: здесь проще будет без регулярок: `res = [x for x in inp.split() if x.isdigit()]`

Comment: к сожалению, нужно использовать регулярки

Comment: еси вокруг чисел пробелы `(?:\s|^)\d+(?=\s|$)`

Comment: а как быть с предложениями начинающимися или заканчивающимися на число? Например: `"10 негритят пошли купаться в море."` Или `"Дайте мне 3."`

Comment: в таких предложениях тоже нужно извлечь числа, поэтому вариант с пробелами нерабочий для этого случая

Comment: в Дайте мне 3. вы не отличите вещественное три или целое

Answer (score 4):

[Пример регулярки](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35912832/5909792):

```
import re

inp = '''ghfjfjfj 5 jfjfkffk 8 jffjkkd 1989 
         fjhfjddkkd 7 jkdkddldll 8.5 '''
res = re.findall(r'\b(?<!\.)\d+(?!\.)\b', inp)
print(', '.join(res))
# 5, 8, 1989, 7
```

---

Способ через поиск целых и вещественных чисел с последующей фильтрацией:

```
import re

inp = '''ghfjfjfj 5 jfjfkffk 8 jffjkkd 1989 
         fjhfjddkkd 7 jkdkddldll 8.5 '''
res = re.findall(r'\b(\d\.\d|\d+)\b', inp)
res = [x for x in res if '.' not in x]
print(', '.join(res))
# 5, 8, 1989, 7
```